# React-Native ScrollView - change pagingEnabled on runtime?

Tags: react-native, scrollview

I want to change the property "pagingEnabled" depending on user interactions.

How I can change the behavior of the `ScrollView` to paging or not paging in runtime based on user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using state to manage value of pageEnabled?
so that

```
<ScrollView pageEnabled={this.state.pageEnabled} ...
```

and then on some user interaction you can use this.setState to toggle the value

```
this.setState({pageEnabled: !this.state.pageEnabled})
```